# Convolution quadrature: difference with Nyquist sampling and discrete convolution?

Tags: convolution, sampling

Convolution Quadrature (CQ) is a method for numerical approximation of convolution integrals [1,2]. It has been widely used in the context of boundary integral equations.

What are the advantages of CQ with respect to simple (Nyquist-satisfying) sampling followed by discrete convolution?

I come from a digital signal processing background and I still haven't grasped why one would use such a complex method like CQ if simple sampling would do.

[1] C. Lubich. Convolution quadrature and discretized operational calculus. I. Numerische Math- ematik, 52(2):129–145, 1988.

[2] C. Lubich. Convolution quadrature and discretized operational calculus. II. Numerische Math- ematik, 52(4):413–425, 1988.

Comment: This isn't at all my area, but have you read Part II of the linked paper? It gives a bunch of examples. It emphasizes that one case when convolution quadrature is appropriate is when the Laplace transform of the kernel is known _a priori_ rather than the literal kernel itself.